# Do you use any custom ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper extensions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, html-helper

I'm interested in seeing what **custom extensions other developers have created for the ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper class**.

I think Microsoft got off to a **great a start**, but as usual, left a lot of **open** holes to fill!

Looks like I am going to have to create some for rendering images, rendering action links as images, and so on.

Thought it might be beneficial to actually **put a list together and save some other developers some time and effort**, and I'll be honest, save me some time as well. =)

If you have any website links to other extension methods for the HtmlHelper class please provide them!

Comment: tip for anyone developing HtmlHelper : PLEASE use TagHelper instead of just constructing HTML by yourself. its much more reliable and safer. if i use your control i want to be sure that tags are closed and if I pass a " to you that it will be encoded to &quot; and I dont need to do it myself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check the [MVC-Contrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) project on Codeplex...

Also, I just found [this](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/archive/2008/08/27/paging-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) paging extension to the HtmlHelper which looks pretty cool, although I've not used it yet.

Comment: That paging extension looks pretty slick.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an article about [building custom controls in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Building_Custom_ASPNET_MVC_Controls.aspx), and I actually use the "Rollup Grid View" that I built in there.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a post to gather useful MVC HtmlHelpers and share them with others; we can grow it up!

Take a look: http://sharplife.net/2008/11/14/UsefulHtmlHelpersForASPNETMVC.aspx (or http://tinyurl.com/mvchelper to remember easily!).

Answer (score 1):

I made quite a few for a project I did at work. The ones that I can think off the top of my head were:

ActionImage, which was the unholy love child of ActionLink and Image.
ScriptBlock, which could write out a JavaScript script block based on some parameters from the ASP.NET.
Textile, which would take a string marked up in [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29) markup and write out that markup as XHTML produced by a [Textile library](http://textilenet.codeplex.com/).

There were a few other more specific ones as well, but I think it's a really neat way of encapsulating blocks of tags.